# bijective and injective maps

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, cardinals

> Find the following maps:
> Find a bijective map $f :\mathbb{R} \to [0,1)$ and an injective map $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}.$

I know some bijective maps from $\mathbb{R}\to (0,1)$, namely $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \dfrac{1-2x}{x(x-1)}$ and $f : \mathbb{R}\to (0,1), f(x) = \frac{1}2 + \frac{1}{\pi} \arctan(x).$ I also know a bijective map from $(0,1) $ to $(0,1],$ which is  defined by $f(x) = x$ if $x\neq \frac{1}{2^n}$ for any $n$ and $f(x) = 2x$ otherwise (this function is injective and surjective).  Also, a bijective map from $(0,1]$ to $[0,1)$ can simply map $x$ to $x$ if $x\in (0,1)$ and $1$ to $0.$ But composing three of these bijective maps to get the required bijection seems more complicated than it should be.

Also, as for an injective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q},$ we can choose a bijective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$, say $f(x) = \frac{1}2 + \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(x)\,\forall x.$ Define $g: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ by $g(x) = x$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ and $g(x) = \pi + x$ otherwise. Then $g\circ f$ gives the desired injective map.

> Is there a shorter way to solve these problems?

Comment: Why do you say that $g$ is a map from $(0,1)$ into $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$?

Comment: I think what you have are good solutions, I don't expect one could fund something much simpler (in particular, expressed by a simple single formula). Another way to get a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $[0,1)$, use that each is the union of countably many disjoint left-closed, right-open intervals, e.g. $\mathbb R=\cup_{n\in\mathbb Z}[n,n+1)$ and $[0,1)=\cup_{n\ge0}[1-2^{-n},1-2^{-(n+1)}).$ @J isn't it because $\pi+$rational$=$ irrational?